# return to previous window on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and couldn't find an answer to to this issue:

I have 3 windows I want to navigate between-
`MainWindow -> Window1 -> Window2`

On `cancel` button click on Window2 I want to return to Window1.

I found this code to navigate between 2 windows, but not between 3 as I need:

**MainWindow:**

```
    private void Window1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 window1 = new Window1();
        window1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

**Window1:**

```
    private void btn_Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btn_Window2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 window2 = new Window2();
        window2 .Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

**Window2:**

```
    private void btn_Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        //what should I write to show Window1 again?
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the way you show your windows like this:

```
private void Window1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    new Window1().ShowDialog();
    ShowDialog();
}
```

And use the `DialogResult` property to hide your windows (except the main window):

```
private void btn_Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = false;
}
```

Comment: This code almost works - it results in showing both Window1 and MainWindow on cancel click of Window2. I want to return to Window1 without the MainWindow showing.

Comment: Yes, I have just [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863139/showdialog-ends-prematurely-if-called-from-hidden-windows/30863739) about that behavior and edited my answer here accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! that works. Important to note that in the MainWindow Show() should be used and not ShowDialog().

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of a navigation service class that holds a stack of navigated windows.

```
public static class NavigationService
{
    static NavigationService()
    {
        NavigationStack.Push(Application.Current.MainWindow);
    } 

    private static readonly Stack<Window> NavigationStack = new Stack<Window>();

    public static void NavigateTo(Window win)
    {
        if(NavigationStack.Count > 0)
            NavigationStack.Peek().Hide();

        NavigationStack.Push(win);
        win.Show();
    }

    public static bool NavigateBack()
    {
        if (NavigationStack.Count <= 1)
            return false;

        NavigationStack.Pop().Hide();
        NavigationStack.Peek().Show();
        return true;
    }

    public static bool CanNavigateBack()
    {
        return NavigationStack.Count > 1;
    }
}
```

You can use it from your views' code behind :

```
    public void OnNextClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateTo(new Window2());
    }

    public void OnPreviousClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        NavigationService.NavigateBack();
    }
```

The static constructor adds the main view started from your App.xaml StartupUri to the navigation stack as the initial view.

If your application has a growing complexity you may also have a look at tools such as [prism navigation system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx).