# Navigating back to the main Window from a loaded page without using a frame in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I loaded a page into a window using
`UserMainPage newPage = new UserMainPage();
this.Content = newPage;`
I have tried going back to the previous Window content while in the loaded UserMainPage by using a button but it opens the Window content in a totally new Window.
Is it possible to go back from the loaded page to the previous window content?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860276/return-to-previous-window-on-wpf

Comment: Personally, I would prefer you to go for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19654812/2819451) that will give better and handy way to navigate views inside window.