# Give Information to main Window

Tags: wpf, class, parent

im pretty new to Coding and I have a Question. I've Created a Main Menu with WPF and Created a Settings Page. How Can I give the Information back for example when someone clicked in the Settings Change My Data so that the Main Window can Open a new Change Page?

Comment: See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860276/return-to-previous-window-on-wpf)

Comment: doesn't work bc im working with pages